# MS Access Multiple Instances of Single Form for different clients

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, multiple-instances

Another question that stumps me. 
I have a continuous form that shows a list of all of our clients at the law firm I work at here. Right now you can double click on a client name where a form (frmContactSummary) then opens up to display all the information for that client. 
Problem is, as it is currently designed only one form can be open for a client at a time. 
We want to be able to open multiple versions or instances of frmContactSummary. 
I borrowed code from Allen Browne's site, which is as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
'Author:    Allen J Browne, July 2004
'Email:     allen@allenbrowne.com
'Found at:  http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html

Public clnClient As New Collection  'Instances of frmClient.

Function OpenAClient() 'ContactID As Integer
    'Purpose:   Open an independent instance of form frmClient.
    Dim frm As Form
    'Debug.Print "ID: " & ID

    'Open a new instance, show it, and set a caption.
    Set frm = New Form_frmContactSummary
    frm.Visible = True
    frm.Caption = frm.Hwnd & ", opened " & Now()

    'Append it to our collection.
    clnClient.Add Item:=frm, Key:=CStr(frm.Hwnd)
    Set frm = Nothing
End Function
```

This works in a way, but it only opens up the first record in our Contact table. We want the instance to open on a specific record, or ID from the Contacts table.
I tried this code near the end:

```
frm.RecordSource = "select * from Contacts where [ID] = " & ContactID
```

But it did not work.. :-(

Any advise would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Ahh... I thought the 'ID' in the code I used above was unique to the Collection of instances that is created via the code to accommodate for the different instances of the form.
I admit, I am not the best coder out there and did a bit of a copy and paste.. trying to adapt Allen Brown's code to fit my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, when you create a instance of a form, you can’t use the common approach of a where clause like this:

```
Docmd.OpenForm "frmContactSummary",,,"id = " & me!id
```

The above of course would work for opening one form.

However, in your case, you need:

Create a new instance of the form
Move/set the form recordsource to ID
Display the form

So we need a means to move or set the form to the ID of the row we just clicked on.

So right after we create the form, then add  this line of code:

```
Set frm = New Form_frmContactSummary

Frm.RecordSource = "select * from Contacts where id = " & me!id
```

And rest of your code follows.

It not clear if the PK (key) of the table Contacts is “id”, or “ContactID”

So your code will be:

```
Frm.RecordSource = "select * from Contacts where id = " & me!id

Or

Frm.RecordSource = "select * from Contacts where Contactid = " & me!ContactID
```

Simply replace “ContactID” in above with a actual PK id used in table contacts. The "Id" has nothing to do with the collection. We are simply building a SQL statement that will pull/set the form to the one row. So the only information required here is what is the PK name in your continues form, and what is the PK name in your frmContactsSummary. (they will be the same name in both forms, and should thus be the same in the sql statement.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The PK being used in this form is "id". Thank you so much Albert! That solved the issue!

Comment: I was close it seems but I was not quite there. What did work for this was, as: Frm.RecordSource = "select * from Contacts where id = " & Form_<"Name of Current Form">!id  ;  So I actually did have to make a small change to what Albert gave.